# Verificar Array(STRING) em coluna Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-10

Boa tarde pessoal,

Preciso fazer UPDATE em uma tabela, mas para isso preciso comparar se os valores de um ARRAY(STRING) estão dentro de uma coluna dessa tabela, exemplo:

```
UPDATE tabelaTeste
SET versao = '2'
    WHERE codigo LIKE ['1','3','4']
```

Alguém pode fornecer aquela ajudinha?

Comment: Faz algumas tentativas e poderemos te ajudar com o erro.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui através da seguinte maneira:

```
update tabelaTeste
SET versao = '2'
    WHERE conta = ANY(['1','3','4'])
```